# Bash global variables not changed when functions is evaled

Tags: bash, shell

I want to call function "B" and pass to it another funcion name (A1, A2, etc), that would be called from it. And in this function, which name is passed, I initialize several variables, but I can't read them from "B" function.

```
function A1
{
    echo "func 1"
    result1="a1"
    return 0
}

function A2
{
    echo "func 2"
    anotherResult="a2"
    #..some other initialization
    return 0
}
#...

function B
{
    output=`$1` #  $1 - function name
    echo output=$output
    echo result1=$result1 # <--- ERROR! result1 is empty!
}

B "A1" # main script runs function B and passes other function name
```

Comment: output=`$1` with backquotes, without backslashes

Comment: and B "A1" at the end is bash code too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function B does not call A1.

Note that `output=$($1)` will not do what you expect, because whatever is running inside `$(...)` will be executed in a different process, and when that process will terminate, the value you set will not be accessible any longer.

So:

```
function B
{
    output=\`$1\` # <-- this will not call the $1 but will only print it

    output=`$1`   # <-- ( $($1) is a better style ) - will call whatever 
                  #     inside $1, but in another process

    $1            # <-- here is the missing call in the current process.
    ...
}
```

You can use redirection e.g. `A1 > tmpfile` a file or a named pipe, to get at the output via the file-system while keeping the side-effect in the current process:

```
function B
{
    $1 > tempfile
    read output < tempfile

    echo output=$output
    echo result1=$result1
}
```

Will do what you expect, but will use `tempfile` on your file-system.

Comment: I need that function writes

output=func 1
result1=a1

Comment: when I called output=\`$1\` - variable output was initialized, but result1 not.

Comment: And I can't call my function $1 twice, because it runs about one minute.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that works! I thought I had to write something like output="eval $1" or exec $1